# Assert is a job is dispatched in the finally callback

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have the following piece of pseudo code

```
Bus::batch([
  new SearchA($a),
  new SearchB($a),
  new SearchC($a),
  new SearchD($a),
  new SearchE($a),
  new SearchF($a),
])
->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
  Log::info('Batch finished');

  if ($condition === true) {
    Log::info('all batch jobs returned no result, falling back');

    SearchFallBack::dispatchSync($a);
                
  }
})
->name('batch-name')
->dispatch();
```

I can assert that the batch contains 6 jobs and the the batch name equals 'batch-name' but I also want to assert that SearchFallBack is dispatched because the condition in the finally block is true.

```
Bus::assertBatched(function (PendingBatchFake $batch) {
  return $batch->name == 'batch-name' && $batch->jobs->count() === 6;
});
```

I tried several solutions but I find no solution asserting that SearchFallBack is dispatched.

Sinc,

Comment: I'm struggling to find a solution for this too.